# How to add movement to my Pocketmine-MP entity?

Tags: php, plugins, pocketmine

I've added [my own entity](https://github.com/and7ey/pmmp-plugin/tree/main/DinosaurPlugin) to pocketmine-mp server:

```
class DinosaurEntity extends Entity { ... }
```

and would like to add random moves for my entity. I don't want to implement my own movement logic. It looks more easy to clone the logic from some existing vanilla entity.

Looking at [Entity.php source code](https://github.com/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/blob/stable/src/entity/Entity.php), I see they generate movements at [`onUpdate()`](https://github.com/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/blob/stable/src/entity/Entity.php#L957) function. Looks like I supposed to use their `_construct` as well.

But I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add an a.i system(because simple movements might seem impractical and ineffective so much) to your entity, incorporating customization such as obtaining random rotations and movement for idle/on, etc. to enhance it as your mention.